# create complicated domain for my attrs attribute

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I want to build below logic for my `attrs` . Can some help me here ?

```
 A OR B OR ( C OR ( (D AND E) OR (F AND G AND H) ) )
```

I tried with below logic

```
['|','|', (A), (B),'|'(C), '|','&amp;', (D), (E),'&amp;', (F),'&amp;' (G),(H)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be quite tricky to form such domains. In those cases you can use `odoo.osv.expression` helpers, which take a list of domains (**not** a list of leafs). Example:

```
>>> from odoo.osv.expression import AND, OR                                                                                                                                                                 

>>> a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h = ([("field_" + x, "=", "value_" + x)] for x in "ABCDEFGH")                                                                                                                             

>>> OR([a, b, OR([c, AND([d, e]), AND([f, g, h])])])                                                                                                                                                        
['|', '|', ('field_A', '=', 'value_A'), ('field_B', '=', 'value_B'), '|', '|', ('field_C', '=', 'value_C'), '&', ('field_D', '=', 'value_D'), ('field_E', '=', 'value_E'), '&', '&', ('field_F', '=', 'value_F'), ('field_G', '=', 'value_G'), ('field_H', '=', 'value_H')]
```

---

Note: I had to convert your variables into valid domains or the methods wouldn't work.

Comment: beautiful Idea, importing the function names made it easy to use.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark as the correct answer. :)